# How can I check to see what resource an ImageItem is currently using?

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a gridview that shows different pictures, and I want to know how I can use an if statement to find out what picture the user clicked on.

```
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            //this is where I want to check for it
            if( )){

            }
            //Create intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

            finish();
            //Start details activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Assuming ItemImage is a custom class you wrote, and it already has the title, why can't you case on that?

Answer (score 1):

View "v" will be the item that the user clicked on.  You can get whatever you need through that object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ImageItem, use ImageButton. It is a button, but as an image, so you can use the common button onClick and stuff.

In this case, you set the onClick function right when you get the button, but you can use the other onClick function with `View v`,  `switch(v.getId())` and the classic code.

```
ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            "ImageButton is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

using onTouchListener()

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // mouse left button pressed
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // mouse left button pressed->non-pressed
            // check processing..
            break;
        return false;
        }
    }
};
```